# locals() defined inside python function do not work

Tags: python

Consider below code:-

```
dct = {'one':[2,3]}
```

Now the below works,

```
for key,val in dct.items():
        locals()[key] = val
print(one)

Result:
    [2, 3]
```

But When I use function which I really want doesn't work. Please help

```
def ff(dct):
    for key,val in dct.items():
        locals()[key] = val
    print(one)
ff(dct)

Result:
NameError: name 'one' is not defined
```

Comment: variable `one` is not defined in the function context

Comment: Maybe worth reading the warning about modifying locals here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: I want to create that variable(Eg 'one') inside function using dictionary. Is there any way I can do it inside the function?

Comment: Don't. Use the dict. Or unpack it as **kwargs

Comment: No, you cannot create local variables dynamically. Did you read the documentation? You almost certainly don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the `locals()` call inside a function is not one that you can use to actually update locals using your method. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) makes that clear:

> `locals()`
>
> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table. Free variables are returned by `locals()` when it is called in function blocks, but not in class blocks. Note that at the module level, `locals()` and `globals()` are the same dictionary.
>
> *Note The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.*

The reason why you cannot update locals using this method is that they are heavily optimised within the CPython source code<sup>(a)</sup>. When you call `locals()`, it actually builds a dictionary (the "update and return" bit) based on these heavily optimised structures and *that* is what you get.

Writing a new key to that dictionary is *not* reflected back to the *actual* locals.

I believe the `globals()` return value *does* allow updates using this method because that's already a dictionary and it just gives you a reference to it, not a copy. That's why your code works outside of a function (see the clause above stating `locals()` and `globals()` are the same thing in that context).

From memory, Python 2 allowed you to do something like `exec "answer = 42"` and that *would* affect the locals. But, as with `print`, this was changed from a statement to a library call in Python 3, so the execution engine really has no idea what it does under the covers, meaning it cant magically bind locals with `exec("answer = 42")`.

I suppose someone *could* request this as a feature since it would make dynamic programming a little easier. Whether it would get through the gauntlet, I have no idea, since the fact that you can provide your *own* `locals` dictionary to `exec()` means that you already have a way to detect variables that were bound by arbitrary code. They'll just be in a *separate* dictionary rather then in the actual locals area.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Access to locals is via known indexes into the stack-frame local variable area, computed at compile time and embedded into the actual bypte code. Being able to add/change variables dynamically would break this optimisation.

This problem was raised as an [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue4831) back in early 2009 and the outcome was that it was too difficult without losing a lot of performance.

Comment: Can we use globals() ?

Comment: @KiranRamamurthy: yes, I believe you can. I wouldn't do that myself, I'd simply pass a different (initially empty) dictionary, populate it, and use it to get values. But then, of course, you just end up with a copy of `dct` so you may as well use `dct` :-)