# Why won't eval() run this line in python?

Tags: python, eval

At first I was getting a syntax error with this code:

```
eval('A'+str(x)+' = np.flip(cv2.imread(r"'+str(path)+'\\'+str(image[x-firstImage])+'", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED),1)')
```

I thought perhaps I messed something up so I tried to start barebones (literally just reading in one image) from:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

x = 1

#Number of pixels in img
column = 500
row = 200

A1 = np.zeros((row,column)) 

path = r'C:\Users\Boyon\Desktop\PhotoFile'
image = 'photo01.tif'

eval('A'+str(x)+' = cv2.imread(r"'+str(path)+'\\'+str(image)+'",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)')
```

but I'm still getting a syntax error. What the code is reading is

```
A1 = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Boyon\Desktop\PhotoFile\photo01.tif",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

which I know works because I had done it just a couple of weeks ago, so I don't know if this is an issue fundamentally with eval? My knowledge on it isn't great and so I'm not sure if what I input into it doesn't work.
The error code is as follows:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    A1 = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Boyon\Desktop\PhotoFile\photo01.tif")
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Why are you trying to `eval` it? Why not just `a1 = cv2.imread(f"{path}\\{image}",cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)`?

Comment: @Yatin invalid syntax

Comment: @Boyon, the _full_ error message, with details and traceback, please. See [ask].

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well Im trying to reproduce another code that uses eval statements, and later on in the program it sorta requires them to be formatted like what I have so I'm just trying to get it to work (reading in just one image) first before I plug it back into my main code and continue on

Comment: @Boyon If I were you, I'd be highly suspicious of any source that's dynamically creating variables using `eval`. There's many different ways of achieving that effect, and dynamic variable creation is probably the worst possible option. Anyways, IIRC, the issue is that `eval` expects an expression, which `=` isn't. You need to use `exec` instead (Again, iirc. I don't use either function because they have very few good use-cases).

Comment: @Carcigenicate Understood, thanks for the explanation. Could I then ask you for a recommendation? My issue is, later on in the code these arrays are references as "Array#[i]" where both # and i are varying, problem is I didn't know how to achieve having # vary unless using said eval statements. Can you recommend a better process?

Comment: @Boyon Instead of creating `A1`, `A2`, `A3`. . . variables, put the objects into a list and refer to them as `images[0]`, `images[1]`, `images[2]`. . . That way, you can use all the list operations on them to filter, iterate them without manually building strings to do a variable lookup. If you have two dimensions (varying letters and numbers), a two dimensional list or another structure simulating one would work well. Then you have `images[0][0]`, `images[0][1]`. . ., or again, just by normal iteration using a `for`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I see what you mean. I'm just wondering, these arrays under A1...An are n x m matrices. I see what you mean if you have changing letters & numbers, luckily just only the number. So would I be able to update the list, i.e A1..An while also indexing the 2d matrices within?

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify because I can't tell from your last comment: do you need a 2D structure, or just a 1D list? You mention only needing a number to index, but also mention 2D matrices.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Not a problem, perhaps I should've been more clear. In essence I need an array of length n, where each element is a 2d array. Problem is I wouldn't know how to index both the initial array, and then elements within the 2d array.

Comment: I mean I guess I can just use a 3d array, I dont really know wtf I was thinking but I guess this would work just as well

Comment: Ya, a 1D list of 2D matrices is essentially a 3D list/array, so you could just access it like `images[1][0][0]` to get the `0,0`th element of the matrix at index 1. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/carcigenicate/475b72cc3516143f1c4cac4012b62d5e) for an example.

Comment: Yes thats exactly it man! I think I was overthinking about it waaay too much but that'll do. Thanks a ton for the ideas, I'll probably be deleting this post soon as it wasn't very helpful and to save me the shame haha, many thanks again !

Comment: Boyon, please don't delete questions just because you consider them not useful to yourself (or, worse, though I'm not accusing *you* of this, just because the asker has gotten the information they need and see no further need for the question). The intent of SO is to be a repository of questions and answers for everyone else in the future as well, and deleting questions "breaks" that feature.

Comment: @paxdiablo That I understand for sure, it just seems as though it didn't get greeted very well, and to which reason I don't really know as I seldom post on here

Comment: Given the reason "debugging details needed", I suspect it's because you hadn't shown the exception output. Since you've now added that, I think your question has everything it needs. It may or may not be re-opened (I've voted for that) but, even closed, it still has useful content.

Comment: Ah understood, thanks for informing me

Answer (score 1):

You cannot `eval` assignments, `eval` is basically just for evaluating things normally found on the *right* of an assignment statement.

You probably should be using `exec` for this, provided you understand and mitigate the risks. For example, see the following code, loosely based on yours:

```
path = r'C:\Users\Boyon\Desktop\PhotoFile'
image = 'photo01.tif'

x = 1
exec('A'+str(x)+' = r"'+str(path)+'\\'+str(image)+'"')
print('EXEC', A1, '\n')

x = 2
A1 = eval(r"str(path)+'\\'+str(image)+str(x)")
print('EVAL1', A1, '\n')

x = 3
eval('A'+str(x)+' = r"'+str(path)+'\\'+str(image)+'"')
print('EVAL2', A1, '\n')
```

The first call, `exec`, will work, and set the global `A1`. The second will also work because you're not attempting an assignment. The third will fail:

```
EXEC C:\Users\Boyon\Desktop\PhotoFile\photo01.tif

EVAL1 C:\Users\Boyon\Desktop\PhotoFile\photo01.tif2

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testprog.py", line 13, in <module>
    eval('A'+str(x)+' = r"'+str(path)+'\\'+str(image)+'"')
  File "<string>", line 1
    A3 = r"C:\Users\Boyon\Desktop\PhotoFile\photo01.tif"
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Just keep in mind you can't use `exec` to set *local* variables inside a function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388571/locals-defined-inside-python-function-do-not-work/63388700#63388700) for details but it's basically caused by the fact that the `locals` dictionary passed by default to `exec` is a *copy* of the actual locals (a dictionary built for heavily optimised internal structures).

However, you can pass your *own* dictionary to `exec` to be treated as the locals and then use that to get at the variables that were set - there's just no easy way (or *any* way, really) to echo that back to the *actual* locals.

The following code shows how to do this:

```
path = '/tmp/PhotoFile'
image = 'photo01.tif'

# Construct dictionary to take "locals".

mydict = {}
for i in range(10):
    exec(f"a{i} = '{path}/photo{9-i:02d}'", globals(), mydict)

# Show how to get at them.

for key in mydict:
    print(f"My dictionary: variable '{key}' is '{mydict[key]}'")
```

And the output is:

```
My dictionary: variable 'a0' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo09'
My dictionary: variable 'a1' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo08'
My dictionary: variable 'a2' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo07'
My dictionary: variable 'a3' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo06'
My dictionary: variable 'a4' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo05'
My dictionary: variable 'a5' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo04'
My dictionary: variable 'a6' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo03'
My dictionary: variable 'a7' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo02'
My dictionary: variable 'a8' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo01'
My dictionary: variable 'a9' is '/tmp/PhotoFile/photo00'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I may need to fundamentally change this then because I would need it to set a local var in a function, so I guess neither will fly.

Comment: Just read your updated answer, thanks man, makes tons of sense. As mentioned, I'll have to fundamentally re-work the whole code then. Cheers